# How delete row without deleting its _ID column value?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i want save number of _ID column in sqlite if its row deleted

```
  if( deleting row in sqlite table without delete _ID column if it "_ID" declared as  `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`== true)
     {How() ;}
  else{do_not_vote_this_question_down();} .
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: save? where? what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: save value of _ID in the same table i mean "i donot want delete its value "

Comment: so do you want to delete the row or not?

Comment: i need delete other row columns values  but not delete _id column value,is this clear ?

Comment: @Error you should use `update comand` to do this

Comment: By the sounds of it, you just want to use an `update` statement to set all the other values to null, except for the `_ID`. Deleting a row has a specific meaning in SQL which means to remove all data of that record.

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about... so you want to update the row?

Comment: @PhanVănLinh is this possible to update other columns values with null ?

Comment: @AndrewBreen  yes that it is

Comment: @pskink how is this question not clear , how it should be if you now understand my point ?

Comment: @Error http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm Try using the examples from here, using the `update` syntax to set the values of the columns you want cleared out.

Comment: @AndrewBreen could you add your answer with simple example ?

Comment: An optimized (memory efficient) solution would be delete the row and save the id in another table with single column id!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm) as a guide to how to use SQL updates in SQLite, you shouldn't delete the row, instead update the values of all other columns to be `null`.

The SQL to achieve this would look like the below:

```
UPDATE YourTable SET column1 = null, column2 = null WHERE someCondition = 'value'
```

Update is used because the ID column of a row represents the unique identifier of a record. If you need to keep this value, you are updating that row, as deleting the row by design will remove all references to that ID.

I question why you need to clear out the data but keep the ID - if you are looking to mark something as "deleted" but keep it for historical purposes, a column should be added called "deleted" that is default false, and then set to true (if you do need to re-access this row).

Comment: yes for historical purpose i must use deleted column instead of updating

Comment: how use deleted column i need tutorial link

Comment: Add a column called deleted. When creating a row, make sure it's value is `false`, and modify any of your `select` statements to filter deleted rows out (e.g. `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE deleted = false`). When updating, update the value of deleted (e.g. `UPDATE MyTable SET deleted = true WHERE myCondition = 'value'`). Then if you want to retrieve "deleted" rows, just change the select from before to filter where deleted is true.